# Why is my output 0? How do I solve it? Language C

Tags: c

I am doing a project for my class. The instruction for this one is: Download the program gpa.c and examine it. This program has several syntax and runtime errors. The program is supposed to return the GPA of a student's transcript that includes several 3 credit hour courses. Fix the program so that it asks for grades of several 3 credit hour courses and then computes the correct GPA value. You may assume that the user always enters correct letter grades.
I download it and here is my code. Did I fix all of the error?
Why the input is always 0 and how do I fix it?????????

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float gpa;
    float numberGrade = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    int i, numCourse;
    char letterGrade, modifier;
    printf("Enter the number of course: ");
    scanf("%d", &numCourse);

    for (i = 0; i < numCourse; i++)
    {
        printf("What grade did you earn?\n");
        printf("Enter A, B, C, D, or F: ");
        scanf("%c\n", &letterGrade);

        switch (letterGrade)
        {
            case 'A':
                numberGrade = 4.0;
            case 'B':
                numberGrade = 3.0;
            case 'C':
                numberGrade = 2.0;
            case 'D':
                numberGrade = 1.0;
            default:
                numberGrade = 0.0;
        }

        printf(
                "Enter modifier - for letter grades A-, etc. + for letter grades B+, etc. , and _ for letter grades A, B, etc.: ");
        scanf("%c\n", &modifier);

        if (modifier == '-')
            numberGrade = numberGrade - 0.3;
        else if (modifier == '+')
            numberGrade = numberGrade + 0.3;

        sum = sum + numberGrade;
    }
    gpa = sum / numCourse;
    printf("The final gpa is %.2f.\n", gpa);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You certainly did not fix all the errors. Period.

Comment: Your switch will give everyone a 0 grade, for one... But seeing as you turn to SO instead of doing this yourself, maybe yours is warranted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: to add to what @StoryTeller said, you're missing a `break;` statement after each `case` body.

Comment: Oh, come one @SouravGhosh. It's not fun when you tell them what I meant :)

Comment: @StoryTeller :D :D Mission accomplished, annoyed someone. :P

Comment: ..and to annoy a little bit more, take a look at how [switch statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm) wroks.

Comment: Don't put `\n` on the end of scanf

Comment: Read about the switch statement in your beginner-level C book. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: Thanks guys!!! I add break after each statement, but the output is still 0.

Comment: Thank you all!!! Problem solved. I found at least 3 errors in my code. 1: no break in the switch. 2: I put \n at the end of scanf, which causes some unexpected results. 3. I did not put a blank space before %c. I do not know how the blank space works, can anyone tell me? Anyway, thank you guys so much for helping!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 problems in your program :

**first** : `scanf` function will read any leading whitespace

the first `scanf("%d", &numCourse)` will work as expected but the next `scanf("%c", &letterGrade)` will consume leading whitespace so your input is incorrect and you will not get the right result.

to solve this problem just put a blank space before the conversion specifier:

```
scanf(" %c", &letterGrade);
```

**second** :

you should add `break` after `switch` cases because it will always take 
`numberGrade = 0.0` as default and will not take other cases

your program solution :

```
int main()
{
    float gpa;
    float numberGrade = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    int i, numCourse;
    char letterGrade, modifier;
    printf("Enter the number of course:");
    scanf(" %d", &numCourse);

    for (i = 0; i < numCourse; i++) {
        printf("What grade did you earn?\n");
        printf("Enter A, B, C, D, or F: ");
        scanf(" %c", &letterGrade);


        switch (letterGrade)
        {
        case 'A': numberGrade = 4.0;
            break;
        case 'B': numberGrade = 3.0;
            break;
        case 'C': numberGrade = 2.0;
            break;
        case 'D': numberGrade = 1.0;
            break;
        default: numberGrade = 0.0;

        }

        printf("Enter modifier - for letter grades A-, etc. + for letter grades B+, etc. , and _ for letter grades A, B, etc.: ");
        scanf(" %c", &modifier);

        if (modifier == '-')
            numberGrade = numberGrade - 0.3;
        else if (modifier == '+')
            numberGrade = numberGrade + 0.3;

        sum = sum + numberGrade;
    }
    gpa = sum / numCourse;
    printf("The final gpa is %.2f.\n", gpa);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am wandering the first point how does it work? I mean what does the leading white space do?

Comment: @YizhiHu `scanf(%c,&letterGrade)` will read only single character so if there is any leading whitespace character (newline,space) it will consume it instead of the input character, you have to be careful when using scanf.

Comment: So I can do leading white space: scanf(" %c",&XXX) every time for safety, right?

Comment: yes in your case you can use `scanf(" %c",CharacterVariable)` for safety

Answer (score 2):

you have to add `break`after every `case` statement

```
switch (letterGrade)
    {
        case 'A':
            numberGrade = 4.0;
            break;
        case 'B':
            numberGrade = 3.0;
            break;
        case 'C':
            numberGrade = 2.0;
            break;
        case 'D':
            numberGrade = 1.0;
            break;
        default:
            numberGrade = 0.0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but the output is still 0 though.

Comment: change this line `scanf("%c\n", &letterGrade);` to `scanf("\n%c", &letterGrade);` if it's work don't forget to accept the answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way switch-case operates is when the first `case` match is found, all the subsequent `case` blocks are executed until the execution hits a `break` statement or end of `switch` block. Switch-case statements act in fall-through manner.

Here, let's say 'B' is the value for `letterGrade`, then all the following `case` blocks will be executed

```
case 'B'
case 'C'
case 'D'
default
```

Since `default` will also get executed, it will mark `numberGrade` to `0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for specific explanation, but the output is still 0 though.

Answer (score -1):

try this one, i have made some changes in your code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float gpa;
    float numberGrade = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    int i, numCourse;
    char letterGrade, modifier;
    printf("Enter the number of course: ");
    scanf("%d", &numCourse);

    for (i = 0; i < numCourse; i++)
    {
        printf("What grade did you earn?\n");
        printf("Enter A, B, C, D, or F: ");
        scanf(" %c", &letterGrade);

        switch (letterGrade)
        {
            case 'A':
                numberGrade = 4.0;
                break;
            case 'B':
                numberGrade = 3.0;
                break;
            case 'C':
                numberGrade = 2.0;
                break;
            case 'D':
                numberGrade = 1.0;
                break;
            default:
                numberGrade = 0.0;
                break;                
        }

        printf(
                "Enter modifier - for letter grades A-, etc. + for letter grades B+, etc. , and _ for letter grades A, B, etc.: ");
        scanf(" %c", &modifier);

        if (modifier == '-')
            numberGrade = numberGrade - 0.3;
        else if (modifier == '+')
            numberGrade = numberGrade + 0.3;

        sum = sum + numberGrade;
    }
    gpa = sum / numCourse;
    printf("The final gpa is %.2f.\n", gpa);
    return 0;
}
```